# How to add image/template/js/css load paths based on variable within app controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I have a bunch of partners whose templates and images are stored below the view, public/images, public/stylesheets, public/javascripts directories.

For example, images for a partner 'foo' are stored in `public/images/foo`

This partner is an instance variable `@partner` which is accessible at the application level.

Problem is, I'm doing this all over the place: `<%= image_tag "/images/#{@partner}/image.jpg" %>` or within locations_controller: `<% redirect_to "/locations/#{@partner}/index" %>` ...

One reason for the load path part of the question rather than using helpers: we have to specifically `<% render :template => "/locations/#{@partner}/index" %>` since Rails looks in /locations/index by default.

How could I make this easier on myself? How could I add to load path once I have `@partner`?

Using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirection in the controller is really bad practice

you should do something like:

```
redirect_to get_path(@partner)
```

then in your controller

```
def get_path(partner)
  case partner
  when "partner1"
    partner1_path
  ...
  end
end
```

Concerning your pictures, you should create a helper.

```
def get_pic(partner, image)
  image_tag "/images/#{partner}/#{image}"
end
```

And in your view

```
<%= get_pic(@partner, "image.jpg" %>
```

Comment: yeah, the whole codebase is bad practice. so this is best solved by using helpers?

Comment: One reason for the load path part of the question rather than using helpers: we have to specifically `<% render :template => "/locations/#{@partner}/index" %>` since Rails looks in /locations/index by default. 

Edited to add this to original post.